# How do the eggs function?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm playing Pocket Edition, and I see chicken laying eggs. However, the eggs were floating around like a thrown item. I know you can use them to spawn chickens and bake cakes, but is it possible that those eggs can spawn more chickens?

Answer (score 5):

Chicken eggs are a dropped item from chickens, they drop eggs randomly. You can pick up the eggs and use them. This will throw the egg, and has a chance of spawning a chicken where it lands (not 100%).

Eggs were added in the most recent PE update.

http://minecraft.wikia.com/wiki/Egg

the eggs will not hatch on their own. They will disappear like any other dropped item.

Answer (score 2):

They are items, and if you leave them alone they'll just disappear after a while like any other item left on the ground.

Comment: Consider adding a source.

Comment: @David Experience? Meh, it's such a basic question that it seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can throw them which can randomly spawn chickens. Good idea if you are low on food, but there is only a 1/8 chance.

Answer (score 0):

They are used to bake cakes and spawn chickens. They cannot be directly eaten,unless you cook them.

Answer (score 0):

When spawning chickens from an egg there is only a 1/10 chance of hatching one but when you do keep it as a 'pet' so you can get more eggs and eventually more chickens.

Answer (score 0):

Chickens randomly lay eggs which you can collect and use to bake cakes, or to spawn more chickens, though it's not a 100% chance. If you ever try to spawn a chicken, and it works, great!

If you want to have lots of chicken, I suggest making fence posts and a fence gate, so that you can either trap a chicken inside, or (if you have enough eggs) spawn a chicken inside the barrier. That way the chicken is yours forever, and will lay eggs for you to bake cake and also get more chicken!